# Scala Macros: c.universe.Tree to c.universe.Name

Tags: scala, macros

I am trying to generate case classes using macros and static annotations.

Is there any way to convert a `c.universe.Tree` into another `c.universe` type, particularly `c.universe.Name`?

Comment: What kind of tree? What do you want to do with the name?

Comment: @TravisBrown I want to use it as the name of a new case class that is generated from within a macro. Ideally, the case class is annotated with a list of parameters that will be stripped to generate the new case class definition.

Comment: Is the tree a string literal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on what kind of tree you have, but in any case you'll want to go from your tree to a string, and then you can create either a `TypeName` or the `TermName` with the `TypeName` and `TermName` constructors.

For example, here our tree is a string literal:

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox.Context

def callFooImpl(c: Context)(name: c.Expr[String]): c.Expr[Unit] = {
  import c.universe._

  val termName: TermName = name.tree match {
    case Literal(Constant(s: String)) => TermName(s)
    case _ => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "Not a string literal")
  }

  c.Expr[Unit](q"$termName.foo()")
}

def callFoo(name: String): Unit = macro callFooImpl

case class Foo(i: Int) {
  def foo(): Unit = println(s"Called foo() on $this")
}
```

And then:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

val myFoo = Foo(10)
callFoo("myFoo")

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

Called foo() on Foo(10)
myFoo: Foo = Foo(10)
```

Here we've deconstructed the string literal tree with `Literal` and `Constant` to get a compile-time string, which we then use to create a `TermName`, which we can use in our generated code.